# How can I prevent that a Client can search a file in any directory of the Server?

Tags: c, linux, security, client-server

For an university project I developed in Linux, using C language, a Client and a Server. When I run my Client I pass as arguments of the program the filenames (one or more) to request to the Server. The Server should search the file with the corresponding name in its current directory and if it finds it, it sends it to the Client. If as filename I use only the name of the file, for example try.txt, it's all ok, but how can I avoid that someone who use my Client try to go up on the path and search file in other directories, for example writing "../try.txt"?

Comment: Too broad. It has to be done by design, not a patch.

Comment: you can execute the server program as a specific linux user and restrict that user's access to only the directory you want, see this question : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101576/give-user-read-write-access-to-only-one-directory

Comment: after you succeed at that you'll probably need to adjust your program to catch permission denied errors or it will crash the server

Comment: if you want a different directory for every different user then you could create a linux user for every different user and apply the same techniques

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You all gave me some good idea

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends how you implemented the search on the server side. The easiest and obvious but not always the right answer would be to strip slashes `/` from the search string you get.

However if you implemented your search with a shell command using `system()` with, for example, `find` and your filename concatenated you need a serious filter function for the user input because otherwise one could execute random shell commands with a prepared search string

Comment: Thank you to your advice, you gave me an idea that should work in my case.